# Linear Transformation Matrix based on a Specific Example

Tags: linear-transformations

Find the matrix of the following linear transformation in the standard bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ for the domain and codomain, respectively.

$T: \mathcal{M}_2 \to \mathcal{M}_2; T(B) = BC-CB$, where $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ \:\:3&4\end{pmatrix}, C = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ \:\:0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

I found that: $T(B) = \begin{pmatrix}-3&-3\\ 0&3\end{pmatrix} = T\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix} + 2T\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix} + 3T\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix} + 4T\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$. How do I proceed from here? I could just say that $T\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-3&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$, etc, but this would be just one possible solution? It could very well be many other solutions from what I can see.

Comment: Are you sure that you’ve transcribed the problem correctly? It’s impossible to determine a linear transformation from its value on only one vector.

Comment: @amd Yes, it is transcribed correctly. Part of the instructions was also: "In addition, verify that $T(v)$ is equivalent to $A[v]_B$ for the indicated vector." This doesn't seem to change things for the first part of the question though.

Comment: The problem is ill-posed if so. You can pick _any_ linear transformation that produces this one result, making the rest of the exercise virtually meaningless. Now, if $T(X)=XC-CX$ for _all_ $2\times2$ matrices, or something along those lines, then that’s a different matter. To me, that’s more likely to be what was meant.